# Where can I find "microsoft.office.interop.excel" in the Assembly / COM browser window?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, reference, ide, project

I wanted to add the reference `microsoft.office.interop.excel` to my project.

I went to Project > Properties > References > and clicked the `Add...` button.

In the `Reference Manager` dialog, I have the following options:

- Assemblies
- Frameworks
- Project folder
- COM
- Search

There is a search window. I typed `microsoft.office.interop.excel`, but it is just not found.

I had to browse for it to locate it manually on my drive.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

`Project menu` > `Add Reference`.
On the COM tab, locate `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library`

That's the reference which contains `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

If you are prompted to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click `Yes`.

Answer (score 1):

You should see it in the Visual Studio Reference Manager Window when you select `COM`.  Look for `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library` (or the version you have installed).  If you don't see it, it needs to be re-registered.  The easiest way to do this is to just re-run it's installation.

To re-install it, find the Primary Interop Assembly executable on your drive download it from Microsoft.  Search for "Office Primary Interop Assembly".  After downloading, run the executable to extract the `msi` file for the PIA.  Run the `msi` file to complete the installation.