# Save Excel spreadsheet as PDF

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, pdf, excel-interop

I'm trying to save an Excel spreadsheet as a PDF file using Visual Basic. I've found some sample code online (see below) but it has me open a Workbook object which Visual Basic doesn't seem to recognize any more. Suggestions...

```
                       ' load Excel file
        Dim workbook As New Workbook()
        workbook.LoadFromFile("D:\test.xlsx")

        ' Set PDF template
        Dim pdfDocument As New PdfDocument()
        pdfDocument.PageSettings.Orientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape
        pdfDocument.PageSettings.Width = 970
        pdfDocument.PageSettings.Height = 850

        'Convert Excel to PDF using the template above
        Dim pdfConverter As New PdfConverter(workbook)
        Dim settings As New PdfConverterSettings()
        settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDocument
        pdfDocument = pdfConverter.Convert(settings)

        ' Save and preview PDF
        pdfDocument.SaveToFile("sample.pdf")
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("sample.pdf")
```

Comment: You need to install a PDF library. e.g. PDFSharp

Comment: Thanks SSS. The error I'm getting is on the Dim workbook As New Workbook() line. It says the Workbook class does not exist. Is this a class that I need to set up? I thought it might be a system class.

Comment: The Workbook class is part of the Interop DLL for Excel, which isn't a part of the System namespace in .NET.  More info on how to reference the Excel interop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817898/where-can-i-find-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-the-assembly-com-browser

Comment: If this is the problem `Dim workbook As New Workbook()` - Sounds like a compile time error. Or is it runtime? Something with your references

Comment: Hi Sean - I followed the instructions outlined in the link you provided but when I looked at the Microsoft..Excel 15.0, it didn't have the .dll that was indicated. Help!

Comment: T.S. - Yes, it is a compile time error and I think you're right - It is a problem with my references. I just need to find out how to fix it. According to Sean, I need an Interop DLL for Excel but I can't find it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what version of visual studio and version of update on it you're using and what framework version you targeting. Also, if you answer to one of us, you need to type @userName, if you want us to receive this message. Usually interop assemblies are shipped with visual studio.  may be, you just didn't install them during setup

Answer (score 2):

You can go simpler by using the `.ExportAsFixedFormat` function, e.g.

```
Dim workbook As New Workbook()
workbook.LoadFromFile("D:\test.xlsx")

workbook.activesheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "D:\test.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

Late-bound version of nutsch's answer..

```
Option Strict Off 'Required for Late Binding     

Module XL
  Sub ExcelPDF()
    Dim xl As Object
    xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim xwb As Object = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\test.xlsx")
    xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "D:\sample.pdf")
    xl.Quit()
  End Sub
End Module
```

P.S. I recommend developing with the Office PIA's (so you get Intellisense & help) and then switching to late-binding before publishing, so you aren't locked into a specific version of Office (also, so you don't need to distribute the PIA's with your app)

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the ways of how you can create PDF out of Excel or for that matter - any program that you can access programmatically (to broaden your experience). It is by using virtual printer. You will need

- Download virtual PDF printer (many are available and some are free). Also, understand what type of PDF any given printer creates - *raster pdf* or *vector pdf*. Raster creates much larger files.
- Install it (virtual printer)
- In code - you usually setup the printer properties and then
- you, in code, open excel using interop and call `Print`, in which you set the printer - your virtual PDF printer and depending on the printer, you set option "Print To File". Some virtual printers don't require that because you preset their properties or even (some printers) registry keys, where you set the file name.

Code examples are usually available from printer vendors. And there are more on different related blogs. Google "virtual printer for .net"

And what I think, if you using older interop/excel (sorry, I can't really tell the version cut off) - this is only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The *Workbook* is not a class of Excel Interop nor a class of System. This sample code is based on [Spire.XLS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/), a 3rd party component which enables users to manipulate Excel file in .NET.  Before you can run the program, you need to download and reference the DLL to your project.

Comment: I am not looking for a solution where there are extra costs involved. As I would need to pay for the Spire.XLS DLL, I will not be using this.